# Why are USB flash drives factory-formatted with noticeable unallocated space at the beginning?

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I just bought a brand new Data Traveler 64GB USB flash drive and noticed it has a strange partition layout with 32MB unallocated free space at the beginning.

I know it's not specific to this exact model.

Why is that?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 57.8 GiB, 62008590336 bytes, 121110528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xXXXXXXXX

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *    60672 121110527 121049856 57.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: @Moab This is irrelevant. Any filesystem is located *inside* partition. I was asking about partition layout (where it starts).

Comment: Why? How would we know, only the manufacturer would know for sure, maybe where the firmware is stored. I suppose you can only see this partition using linux commands, no way to see this in windows.